# Show that $\operatorname{cov}(x,a + by) = b \operatorname{cov}(x,y)$

Tags: statistics, proof-writing, covariance

> Let $x$ and $y$ be jointly distributed numeric variables and let $z=a+by$ , where $a$ and $b$ are constants. Show that $\operatorname{cov}(x,z)=b\, \operatorname{cov}(x,y)$.

Here's what I have so far, but then I got stuck.

[image]

Finished.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the most elegant proof, but you're almost there!

**Hint:** Note that $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i a = a\,n\,\mu(x)$, and $\mu(a + by) = a + b\mu(y)$.  All the terms from the left that have an $a$ in them should "cancel out".

Comment: Those two facts will help a lot, thanks!  I couldn't figure out how to deal with the a+by inside the mu.